# Android studio calendarview events from arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, calendarview

Is there a way where a calendarview can add events from an arraylist?

for example. Can this array be an event inside a calendarview based from the `acceptDate`? Thanks guys.

```
[  
{  
  "acceptedID":"118",
  "acceptDate":"3\/1\/2017",
  "acceptTime":"12:00 AM",
  "resID":"155"
  },
  {  
  "acceptedID":"116",
  "acceptDate":"2\/27\/2017",
  "acceptTime":"12:00 AM",
  "resID":"153"
   },
   {  
  "acceptedID":"114",
  "acceptDate":"2\/28\/2017",
  "acceptTime":"12:00 AM",
  "resID":"151"
}
]
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Do you want to set Alarms based on the dates in your array list?

Comment: @bc004346 - I just want to highlight the date that is stated on my arraylist

Answer (score 0):

I don't think native CalendarView will help you. I was not able to get custom highlighting with that. However, I recommend [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) for custom highlighting. I don't want to plagiarize documentation that is already out there, but here is how you can easy it is:

```
ColorDrawable blue = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
ColorDrawable green = new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN);
caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(blue, blueDate);
caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(green, greenDate);
```

Comment: Can this be dynamic? Everytime a new date is added in the array list it will add a new date?

Comment: *You* can make it dynamic with the help of [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)